# minimalization of cos-distance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors, machine-learning

About single perceptron problem
Dim $X_n = \{w_1x_1, w_2x_2, w_3x_3, w_4x_4,......, w_nx_n\}$ as vector
($X_n$)supervised learning　data

$\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,......x_n\} $ are input values of analasing data.

$\{w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4,......w_n\} $are weight of $X$
we have a vector $Y_n\{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4........y_n\}$ that is to be compared.

we will compare them by $cos\theta$-distance

> $cos\theta = X_nY_n^T/|X||Y|$

the fomula above is Loss function.

if data $X_n$ is correct $cos\theta$ will be increaced,
if not $cos \theta$ will decreace;
how to adjust weight $\{w_1, w_2. w_3, ......w_n\}$

Comment: which are the variable that you get to optimize? what are the constraint on the variables?

Comment: You can minimalize by setting all the weights to 0, then your $v_iv_c^T = 0$ haha. Joking aside, I believe you want to find the closest word to a given vector, something like word2vec's most_similar_cosmul()?

Comment: Koo Zhengqun yes, but it cannot solved by softmax function

Comment: @石原秀一 Use the at sign to ping another user or he might not be notified.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh thank you

Comment: @Koo Zhengqun yes, but it cannot solved by softmax function –

Comment: I think we need more context. What do you mean by _"update equation"_? Do you mean a word-by-word replacement? Which words do you want to replace? Trivially replacing every word minimizes distance, but I assume that's not what you want. Are you using a method like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909519 to calculate cosine similarity?

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh I just edited it.

Comment: @Koo Zhengqun problem edited

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}$ be a $n$-dimensional vector. Let the weights $W$ also be an unknown vector, defined similarily.

Let $M = IX = \begin{bmatrix}x_1&&&\\&x_2&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&x_n\end{bmatrix}$ be a diagonal matrix.

By adjusting the weights, you are transforming $X$ to some other vector. This is equivalent to a linear transformation, or a matrix-vector multiplication of $MW$.

To maximize the resulting cosine similarity between $MW$ and $Y$, just make sure $MW$ points in the same direction as $Y$, such that $MW = \alpha Y$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

If any diagonal elements in $M$ are zero, delete the entire row corresponding to that element. Cosine similarity is not affected. As a result, we have an invertible diagonal matrix $M$. The inverse of a diagonal matrix is the reciprocal of each diagonal element.

And we solved for the weights, $W = \alpha M^{-1} \cdot Y$. There are infinite solutions to $W$, and the set of solutions forms a line.